# How to change pagination text in PagedList Pager

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to use [→] instead of [>>]
and I want to use [←] instead of [<<]

Is there way of change text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change it via javascript/jquery, something like this

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('ul.pagination li.PagedList-skipToNext a').html("→");
        $('ul.pagination li.PagedList-skipToPrevious a').html("←");
    });
</script>
```

Output:
[image]